# identity matrix of ridge regression equation

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, ridge-regression

I am trying to understand the equation of ridge regression but I have a hard time with it.
I would like to know what the identity matrix *I*  of the equation below represents. I'm not sure what the shape of this identity matrix should be. Thank you.

β=(X<sup>T</sup>X+λ*I*)<sup>-1</sup> X<sup>T</sup> y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, $X$ is $n\times p$, where $n$ is the number of samples and $p$ is the number of features. So, the shape of $\lambda I$ should be $p\times p$ in order for the expression to be mathematically correct.

The identity term comes from the loss function of the Ridge Regression:
$$L=||X\beta-y||^2+{\lambda}||\beta||^2 = (X\beta-y)^T(X\beta-y)+{\lambda}\beta^T\beta $$
where we differentiate the expression wrt $\beta$ and equate to zero:
$$2X^TX\beta-2X^Ty+2\lambda\beta=0\rightarrow (X^TX+\lambda I)\beta=X^Ty$$
and when multiplied each side with inverse of the matrix LHS , your expression comes out.